# access linux system from windows using teamviewer?

Tags: linux

i am trying to get the remote access from windows system to linux system using teamviewer but when the connection is established the windows system sees the black screen. so anyone can help me how to establish the fair connection.

Comment: On a side note on the off-topic: StackExchange also features the askubuntu-section, where this question might get more answers. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem - for me with two solutions. On some systems, it just took about 30sec for the screen to build up (in that case, just be patient) and in the other case, there was a driver problem. Try to change the driver to the default ubuntu one and deactivate the proprietary hardware driver in that case.